# How to transfer SPL tokens via CPI in Anchor

Tags: anchor, spl-token, cpi

I'm trying to transfer SPL tokens from a PDA to an user account via CPI but I'm facing "instruction spent from the balance of an account it does not own" error.

The PDA is initialized via `create_subscription` instruction

```
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = signer,
        token::mint = mint,
        token::authority = subscription_account,
    )]
    pub subscription_vault: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>
```

The SPL token transfer takes place in the `cancel_subscription`

```
#[account(
        mut,
        close = user_pubkey, 
        constraint = subscription_vault.owner == subscription_account.key() @ CustomError::VaultOwnerMisMatch
    )]
    pub subscription_vault: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>
```

The SPL token transfer CPI is as follows

```
let seeds: &[&[&[u8]]; 1] = &[&[
        SUB_ACC_SEED,
        user_pubkey.as_ref(),
        &subscription_acc.id,
        &[subscription_acc.bump],
    ]];
    let transfer_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
        ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
        TransferChecked {
            from: ctx.accounts.subscription_vault.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.user_ata.to_account_info(),
            authority: subscription_acc.to_account_info(),
            mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
        },
        seeds,
    );
    transfer_checked(
        transfer_ctx,
        ctx.accounts.subscription_vault.amount,
        ctx.accounts.mint.decimals,
    )?;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're seeing is due to the `close` constraint on a `TokenAccount`. The error is being thrown because the `TokenAccount` is owned by the Token Program and not your program.

To close the `TokenAccount`, you'll need to make a CPI to the Token Program's `close_account` instruction. In your `cancel_subscription` instruction you would just add a second CPI after the transfer CPI.

Here is an example of how to set up the `close_account` CPI.

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::token::{close_account, CloseAccount, Mint, Token, TokenAccount};

declare_id!("Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS");

#[program]
pub mod test {
    use super::*;

    pub fn create_token_account(_ctx: Context<CreateTokenAccount>) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn close_token_account(ctx: Context<CloseTokenAccount>) -> Result<()> {
        let bump = *ctx.bumps.get("token_account").unwrap();
        let signer: &[&[&[u8]]] = &[&[b"token", &[bump]]];

        close_account(CpiContext::new_with_signer(
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            CloseAccount {
                account: ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
                destination: ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
                authority: ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
            },
            signer,
        ))?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateTokenAccount<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [b"token"],
        bump,
        payer = signer,
        token::mint = mint,
        token::authority = token_account
    )]
    pub token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CloseTokenAccount<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"token"],
        bump
    )]
    pub token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
}
```

Note that in the example above, the same PDA is used as both the address and authority of the `TokenAccount`.

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot, so my instruction needed to have two separate CPIs - one to transfer the remaining SPL tokens to an user's account and other to close the token account